# Reading Paired Data Into R

Tags: r

I have a bunch of paired data that I want to read into a variable in R, but I can't figure out the syntax. The data is text in the following format:

```
(dist1, time1) (dist2, time2) (dist3, time3) ... etc.
```

I've tried reading this in as a data.frame, data.table, or list. However, when I try something like this

```
x <- data.frame((dist1, time1), (dist2, time2), (dist3, time3))
```

I get the error:  Error: unexpected ',' in "x <- data.frame((0.10,"

Thanks for any /all help.

Comment: Do you have objects in the global env

Comment: do you have a character vector in the format "(dist1, time1) (dist2, time2) (dist3, time3)..." and you want to create a data frame with two columns dist and time?

Comment: I'm trying to read the paired data in. I don't already have it "in" anything. That's what I'm trying to do, get the data into an R object that I can manipulate, whether that's a character vector, data frame, matrix, or whatever.

Comment: @dave is it the data already read or you want to get the data from the folder

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is `dist1`, `time1`. Are those vector with values? Are those strings? It would be helpful if you provide an actual small example and show how your output would look.

Comment: Here is an example of the data:  (0.010, 0.570) (0.017, 0.677) (0.224, 0.705)

Comment: Added a little more here since my edit time ran out...Here is an example of the data:  (0.010, 0.570) (0.017, 0.677) (0.224, 0.705) - add about 10 more of these and you'll get a full line. As you can see, these are numeric values and, while in a file, (right now) I'm not trying to read the file. I'm just copy/pasting certain lines and trying to see what the data will look like in a plot. So, how do i get these numbers into x (as in, x <- )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the objects in a `list`, then with `Map` concantenate together

```
x <- do.call(cbind, Map(cbind, 
       mget(ls(pattern= '^dist\\d+$')), 
       mget(ls(pattern = '^time\\d+$'))))
```

---

It can also done with

```
data.frame(mget(c(rbind(paste0('dist', 1:3), paste0('time', 1:3)))))
```

#### Update

If we want to read from strings, use `readLines`

```
v1 <- readLines(textConnection('(0.010, 0.570) (0.017, 0.677) (0.224, 0.705)'))
df1 <- read.csv(text = gsub("[()]", "", 
      gsub("\\) \\(", "\n", v1)), header = FALSE)
```

-output

```
df1
#     V1    V2
#1 0.010 0.570
#2 0.017 0.677
#3 0.224 0.705
```

Comment: Since I'm not an R aficionado, can you be a bit more specific by using my example data from above?

Comment: @dave Sure.  My only doubt with your post is whether the 'dist1', 'dist2', 'time1', 'time2' are objects created in R i.e. `dist1 <- rnorm(25); dist2 <- 1:25; time1 <- 1:25, time2 <- 26:50` or is it is `time1.txt`, `dist1.txt` you want to read?

Comment: No, my data is not already in R. I'm trying to get it into an R object but don't know how. Forget trying to read a file in, I think I can figure that out. What I can't figure out is how to get this data (0.010, 0.570) (0.017, 0.677) (0.224, 0.705) into an R object. Thanks.

Comment: @dave is it in a file or is it a string?  You can do `v1 <- readLines(textConnection('0.010, 0.570) (0.017, 0.677) (0.224, 0.705)'))`

Comment: yes, that does read in the line into a character type. Thank you. Is there an "easy" way to now convert the type to a data.frame or something else where the dist/time values are more easily manipulated /plotted?

Comment: @akron  This worked great - very elegant, even if you did you my nemesis, grep. Marked as accepted, with much thanks.